# How to echo a hyperlink with a variable?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Getting these hyperlinks right and mixing HTML with PHP seems to be a constant source of sorrow for me. Whats wrong with this hyperlink?

```
echo '<a href = "googler.php?query='.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">$suggestion[$ss_count]</a><br>;
```

Comment: Try `echo '<a href = "googler.php?query='.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'.$suggestion[$ss_count].'</a><br>;`

Comment: What is the value of `$suggestion`? What is the value of `$$ss_count`? (Why are you using variable variables anyway, they are evil nightmares of debug hell and we have arrays)? What HTML do you get when you run that PHP? What HTML do you expect to get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it should be

```
echo '<a href = "googler.php?query='.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'.$suggestion[$ss_count].'</a><br>';
```

Within single quotes variables are not interpolated so you have to pull the link text out of the string literal.

Comment: too bad I repped out after the first upvote :(

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

try it ..!!

```
echo '<a href = "googler.php?query='.$suggestion[$ss_count].'">'.$suggestion[$ss_count].'</a><br>';
```

Comment: How is this different from @OrangePill's solution above?

Comment: not different buddy we posted nearly at the same time

Answer (score -3):

you all missing the point.

**JUST USE BACKSLASH**

Comment: Show the correct use of backslash in this case.

Comment: I would love to know how `JUST USE BACKSLASH` would fix this problem. Please share.